# Issue sending all Active Campaign tags to Intercom via Zapier

Tags: zapier, intercom

Currently trying to use a Zap to update all tags in Intercom from Active campaign.

This is the code I'm using and to a degree it works.

```
var contactTags = {};

var newTagArray = inputData.tagList.split(', ');
for (var i=0; i< newTagArray.length; ++i) {
    contactTags[i] = newTagArray[i];
}
output = {"Contact Tags":contactTags};
```

The code process and outputs all the relevant tags however the problem is that when I edit the Zap Intercom Action I can only select one of the tags instead of all the tags...

[image: Screen shot of choices for Intercom Action]

you can see form the screen shot that only 'Contact Tags 0' & 'Contact Tags 1' can be selected as the field in put...

I need to have all update...

Comment: are there more tags that you are missing? Also, what format does intercom expect for the tag input? it's not clear what's wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you insert a formatter step and use 'Line-Item to Text' to convert the array to a delimited text field

https://zapier.com/help/formatter/#create-a-tag-text-field-using-the-line-item-to-text-utility